# Problem with converting IP addresses in C++

Tags: c++, ip-address

I need to find the IP address of my node in my code. Currently, I have this line:this line:

```
IPv4Address addr = nb_ipv4->GetAddress (maininterface , 0);
```

In this line, I expect to get the IP address for my main interface, but instead I see this error:

```
error:conversion from 'ns3::Ipv4InterfaceAddress' to non-scalar type 'ns3::Ipv4Address'
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Comment: Sure doesn't look like C to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that must be tagged as C++, and (if it is [The ns-3 network simulator](http://www.nsnam.org/)) you must do this:

```
IPv4Address addr = nb_ipv4->GetAddress(maininterface).GetLocal();
```